# How can I get user's choice using Tkinter.StringVar?

Tags: python, user-interface, python-2.7, tkinter

I am writing a GUI code using Tkinter in python:

```
var_alg_name = Tk.StringVar(board, 'Bilinear')
Tk.Label(board, text = 'Algorithm Name: ').pack(side = 'left')
ttk.Combobox(board, textvariable = var_alg_name, values=['Bilinear', 'Idw']).pack(side = 'left')
```

I want to get use's choice when a user choose a option in the list.

By searching help command, I found .trace to call a callback foo, but how can I get the value inside foo?

Comment: possible duplicate of [python, tkinter: how to select an item in ttk.Combobox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876518/python-tkinter-how-to-select-an-item-in-ttk-combobox)

Answer (score 1):

You simply call `var_alg_name.get()`, assuming that `var_alg_name` is accessible in the scope where you're trying to get the value. See [Set a default value for a ttk Combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6876518/7432) for an example.