# Tkinter ttk Combobox Default Value

Tags: python, combobox, tkinter, ttk

I'm building a Tkinter application and I came across an issue with setting a default value to a combobox.  I managed to fix the problem, but I am curious to know why it worked and I would like to know if there is a better way to do it.

I have a `tk.Toplevel()` window pop up with a combobox using the fowling code:

```
class add_equation():

    def __init__(self):

        self.add_window = tk.Toplevel()
        self.add_window.title("Add Equation Set")
        self.add_window.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        self.name_entry_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.name_entry = ttk.Entry(self.add_window, textvariable=self.name_entry_var, width=30)
        self.name_entry.grid(row=1, columnspan=2, stick="w")

        self.equation_type_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.equation_type = ttk.Combobox(self.add_window, textvariable=self.equation_type_var, values=("System", "Exact", "Import Point List..."), state="readonly", width=28, postcommand =lambda: self.add_window.update())
        self.equation_type.current(0)
        self.equation_type.grid(row=2, columnspan=2, sticky="w")

        self.add_window.update()
```

The class `add_quation()` is called in the following bit of code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Solver_App(tk.Tk, ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        list_frame = ttk.Frame(self, height=50)
        list_frame.pack(side="top", fill="y", expand=True, anchor="w")

        # Button that will call the class add_equation that creates a new window.
        add_button = ttk.Button(list_frame, text="Add Equation Set", command=add_equation)
        add_button.pack(side="top", expand=False, fill="x", padx=10, pady=5, anchor="n")

app = Solver_App()
app.mainloop()
```

Looking back at the `add_equation()` class, if you remove `self.equation_type.current(0)` or `postcommand =lambda: self.add_window.update()`, the default value will no longer show, but with both, it works just fine. Why is it working like this instead of only having `self.equation_type.current(0)`?

I've tried to find a more elegant way of doing this, and I found something related [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876518/set-a-default-value-for-a-ttk-combobox), but I had no luck implementing that method and I assume calling `add_equation()` from a button command may have something to do with that.

*I'm using Python 3.4 on Mac OS X Yosemite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is probably because you're creating a window by calling the `add_equation` constructor, and that window is immediately garbage collected (or atleast the python handle to it is) so never gets properly refreshed.

I'd rewrite it as something like this:

```
class Equation_Window(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self):

        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)

        self.title("Add Equation Set")
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        self.name_entry_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.name_entry = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.name_entry_var, width=30)
        self.name_entry.grid(row=1, columnspan=2, stick="w")

        self.equation_type_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.equation_type = ttk.Combobox(self, textvariable=self.equation_type_var, values=("System", "Exact", "Import Point List..."), state="readonly", width=28)
        self.equation_type.current(0)
        self.equation_type.grid(row=2, columnspan=2, sticky="w")

def add_equation():
    w = Equation_Window()
    w.wait_window()
```

(everything else remains the same)

I've changed the your `add_equation` class to something derived from a `tk.Toplevel` (and renamed it), which I think makes more sense. I've then made `add_equation` a function, and called `wait_window` (which acts like `mainloop` but just for one window). `wait_window` will keep `w` alive until the window is closed, and so everything gets refreshed properly.