# How to display combobox in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Working on a small project for a currency converter using Tkinter for a gui.
I have the below code but it seems I have an error in combobox as it throws an error.

What am I missing?

```
Currency1_value=0
Entry1=Entry(window,textvariable=Currency1_value)
Entry1.grid(row=1,column=0)

CurrencyCombo=Combobox(window, state="readonly", values=("one", "two", "three"))
CurrencyCombo.grid(row=1,column=1)
```

Comment: What is the error? Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The `textvariable=` option of any widget has to be one of the specific Tkinter variable types, such as `StringVar`.  An ordinary Python variable is completely unusable here.

Comment: The error is; 
NameError: name 'Combobox' is not defined

Comment: Combobox is part of **Ttk** so you'll have to `from tkinter import ttk` and use `CurrencyCombo = ttk.Combobox(...`. I'm posting an example below.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

combotext = tk.StringVar()
combotext.set('Select')

box = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable=combotext, state='readonly')
box.pack()
box['values'] = ("Camembert",
                 "Brie",
                 "Tilsit",
                 "Stilton")

def callback_function(event):
    print('You selected:', combotext.get())

root.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', callback_function)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Not sure if I'm doing this wrong but the selector is blank before you click on it and pick an option.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm getting the text "Select" in the box at first. Are you running the exact same code?

Comment: Yeah I adapted the code for my own project.  This thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876518/set-a-default-value-for-a-ttk-combobox) ended up giving me the answer.  Since I had a function I needed to first put "global combotext" so that it remained in memory.